# python error al tomar ValueError

Tags: python

Ya hay algunos post en los que hablan de esta excepción pero no vi en ninguno lo que pasa en esta codigo. y es lo siguiente..El código recibe un numero entero del usuario y lo usa para devolver el indice de una lista, pero al ingresarle un dato tipo str saltaria un error. La cosa es que aplique el except ValueError, pero nunca lo toma, me salta el error en consola en vez del mensaje pre establecido.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
lista_numeros = [6,14,11,3,2,1,15,19]
numero_elejido = int(input("Elija la posicion a mostrar en la lista "))

try:
    print(lista_numeros[numero_elejido])


except ValueError:
    print("Introduza el numero de forma numerica, no textual")
except IndexError:
    print("La posicion elejida es inexistente")
    
finally:
    print("Adios!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error sucede porque la evaluación de entrada de usuario `int(input())` está fuera de la captura de errores, o sea, fuera del bloque `try - except`.

Debe quedar así:

```
lista_numeros = [6,14,11,3,2,1,15,19]    
try:
    numero_elejido = int(input("Elija la posicion a mostrar en la lista "))
    print(lista_numeros[numero_elejido])

except ValueError:
    print("Introduza el numero de forma numerica, no textual")
.
.
.
```

Ahora si, al introducir un alfanumérico aparecerá el siguiente error:

> Introduza el numero de forma numerica, no textual

Comment: Gracias, me fue útil! termino siendo un NoobError lo mio jajaj